# highcharts bubble chart: can i group data?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, bubble-chart

im looking to see if it's possible to group data in a highcharts bubble chart.  I can't seem to find any suitable way to do this:

[image]

Basically, i want to be able to not have a million bubbles on my chart when "zoomed out"...

Just wondering if highcharts could somehow group the points that are close to eachother together so that i could "drill into" the various groups on the chart...

Any help or direction is greatly appreciated...

Thanks!

Comment: It's not supported, sorry. You can create an idea [here](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general). [Black Label](http://www.blacklabel.pl/) may help you also.